# CandleStickChart with visible values on open and close of each candle

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I would like to show both open (top) and close (bottom) value of each candle in CandleStickChart. By default only top (open) is visible (picture below).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently that is **not possible by default**, you will have to modify the library (only slightly) to get what you want.

I am thinking about including such a feature in the future though.